# Angular CLI production build, not known element

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my the html template of my main component I use the elements from components from a module that I have imported. When I try to build this I get the following error.

```
'df-dashboard-widget' is not a known element:
1. If 'df-dashboard-widget' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'df-dashboard-widget' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

And also this error:

```
ERROR in Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'df-dashboard-grid'.
1. If 'df-dashboard-grid' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'df-dashboard-grid' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

My HTML template looks like this:

```
<df-dashboard-grid [options]="options">
  <df-dashboard-widget [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="getComponent(item.tag); injector: getProvider(item)"></ng-container>
  </df-dashboard-widget>
</df-dashboard-grid>
```

I have imported the module that has the `df-dashboard-grid` component, and this component is **exported**. The same issue happens with `df-dashboard-widget`. Also a error says that `ngComponentOutlet` is not a property of `ng-container` eventhough I have imported the `CommonModule` from Angular. My main module decorator looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    DashboardGridModule
  ].concat(Configuration.initialization.modules),
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [DashboardComponent]
})
```

The used module with the components decorator looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardGridComponent,
    DashboardWidgetComponent,
    DashboardGuideComponent,
    DashboardPreviewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [DashboardGridComponent, DashboardWidgetComponent],
})
```

This error only happens when in production mode. In development mode, everything just works fine.

Comment: export all components

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this question myself. Apperently it has to do with this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    DashboardGridModule
  ].concat(Configuration.initialization.modules),
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [DashboardComponent]
})
```

In my Configuration file I have an array of modules that I use as well (because of reasons). In a decorator (or at least the decorator of the main module) you are not allowed to have any functions inside the decorator even though it returns a valid datatype.

I have solved this issue by adding another module that I call `ImportModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: Configuration.initialization.modules,
  exports: Configuration.entryComponents,
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
```

This works for me, because I have a file with all the used modules and components are in a separate constant file. The Configuration has a array of all the used modules, entryComponents is an array of all the used components. In the main module I import this module.